# what is the elementary Lab devices (and their specifications) for building superconducting qubits?

Tags: experimental-realization, superconducting-quantum-computing

suppose I want to build a superconducting qubit, how can I find the Lab Devices and specifications which are nessecarry to build it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert of superconducting qubits, but I work around some. A non-exhaustive list of what you would need includes:

- Some sort of photolithography system to create patterns for the structures of your SC qubit
- A wet bench to develop those patterns, and to initially clean your samples
- A method of depositing material like a sputtering system or electron beam evaporator
- Some sort of plasma etcher to remove material and clean surfaces

Ideally, you'd do all of this inside of a cleanroom to minimize contamination. For more information, you could check out the supplemental information of SC qubit papers because they usual describe their fabrication process, although maybe not to the level of detail if you're just getting started.